# How do I display an ImageView underneath the middle of a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-linearlayout

So in my XML I have a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout ...>
 ...
</LinearLayout>
```

But I want to display an ImageView in the background of the LinearLayout, in the center, behind everything. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work, just took everything over (+rendering problems)

Comment: @The29thSaltshaker make sure that the image view is behind all you other views/content within the linear layout.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai you miss closing tag `</FrameLayout>`

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara it was there, it was just a formatting issue. Thanks for pointng that out.

Answer (score 1):

Add `FrameLayout` to contain `ImageView` and `LinearLayout`, something like this:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent" >
    <ImageView 
        android:src = "@drawable/your_own_image"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity= "center" />
    <LinearLayout>
    ...
    <LinearLayout> 
</FrameLayout>
```

FrameLayout will display child views from the first view to last. So ImageView will be display behind LinearLayout.